# How can I find consecutive active weeks in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

What I would like to do is find the number of consecutive weeks that someone is active on Sundays and assign them a value. They have to participate in at least 2 races a day to be counted as active for the week.

If they are active for 2 consecutive weeks I would like to assign a value of 100, 3 consecutive weeks a value of 200, 4 consecutive weeks a value of 300, and continuing up to 9 consecutive weeks.

My difficulty is not determining consecutive weeks, but breaks in between consecutive dates. Suppose the following dataset:

```
CustomerID  RaceDate    Races
1           2/2/2014    2
1           2/9/2014    5
1           2/16/2014   3
1           2/23/2014   3
1           3/2/2014    4
1           3/9/2014    3
1           3/16/2014   3
2           2/2/2014    2
2           2/9/2014    3
2           3/2/2014    2
2           3/9/2014    4  
2           3/16/2014   3
```

CustomerID 1 would have 7 consecutive weeks for a value of 600.

The hard part for me is CustomerID 2. They would have 2 consecutive weeks AND 3 consecutive weeks. So their total value would be 100 + 200 = 300.

I would like to be able to do this with any different combination of consecutive weeks.

Any help please?

EDIT: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Consider inner joining the table to itself. Join the two on something like this psuedocode: `t1.customerid = t2.customerid and date_diff('w', t1.racedate, t2.racedate) = 1`

Comment: According to your data there are a number of non-consecutive weeks meaning that your current result set is incorrect.

Comment: I've amended my dataset. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking for sequential values, there is a simple observation that helps.  If you subtract a sequence from the dates then the value is a constant.  You can use this as a grouping mechanism

```
select CustomerId, min(RaceDate) as seqStart, max(RaceDate) as seqEnd,
       count(*) as NumDaysRaced
from (select t.*,
              dateadd(week, - row_number() over (partition by customerID, RaceDate),
                      RaceDate) as grp
      from table t
      where races >= 2
     ) t
group by CustomerId, grp;
```

You can then use this to get your final "points":

```
select CustomerId,
       sum(case when NumDaysRaced > 1 then (NumDaysRaced - 1) * 100 else 0 end) as Points
from (select CustomerId, min(RaceDate) as seqStart, max(RaceDate) as seqEnd,
             count(*) as NumDaysRaced
      from (select t.*,
                    dateadd(week, - row_number() over (partition by customerID, RaceDate),
                            RaceDate) as grp
            from table t
            where races >= 2
           ) t
      group by CustomerId, grp
     ) c
group by CustomerId;
```

Comment: Shoudnt be NumdaysRaced -1?

Comment: Works like a charm. I had to make one small change to the row_number() over clause. Instead of a comma, I had to specify Order By RaceDate.