# Count successive weeks in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

I am working on SQL Server

I have the following dataset :

```
Shop_ID     Product_Id     Date     Week     Year
0001             A      2015-01-26    5      2015
0001             A      2015-02-02    6      2015
0001             B      2015-01-03    1      2015
0002             C      2015-01-15    3      2015
0002             C      2015-01-26    5      2015
0002             C      2015-02-02    6      2015
```

What I'd like to create is variable that says when a product is sold in the same shop during 2 successive weeks. Here I would have then :

```
Shop_ID     Product_Id     Date     Week     Year     Sale
0001             A      2015-01-26    5      2015       0
0001             A      2015-02-02    6      2015       1
0001             B      2015-01-03    1      2015       0
0002             C      2015-01-15    3      2015       0
0002             C      2015-01-26    5      2015       0
0002             C      2015-02-02    6      2015       1
```

I have read a few things on a similar topic, here for example :
[How can I find consecutive active weeks in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143174/how-can-i-find-consecutive-active-weeks-in-sql)

but I am struggling with replicating this on my case ... especially due to the fact that I am considering weeks and not days.

In the end, I would also like to be able to allow for gaps, meaning that if a product is sold 3 weeks in a row - then not sold anymore - then again 5 weeks in a row, I would like to take the max of these values. But I guess once I have created a variable such as "Sale" above, it would be easy to do so.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LAG to have running week count:

```
Create table #Sales (Shop_ID int, Product_Id char(1), [Date] date, [Week] int, [Year] int)

    Insert into #Sales Values (1, 'A', '2015-01-26', 5, 2015)
    Insert into #Sales Values (1, 'A', '2015-02-02', 6, 2015)
    Insert into #Sales Values (1, 'B', '2015-01-03', 1, 2015)
    Insert into #Sales Values (2, 'C', '2015-01-15', 3, 2015)
    Insert into #Sales Values (2, 'C', '2015-01-26', 5, 2015)
    Insert into #Sales Values (2, 'C', '2015-01-02', 6, 2015)
    Insert into #Sales Values (2, 'C', '2015-01-03', 7, 2015)


    select a.shop_id, a.product_id, a.[date], a.[week], a.[year], sum([WeekSale]) OVER (PARTITION BY  [Shop_ID], [Product_ID], [Year]  ORDER BY  [Shop_ID], [Product_ID], [Year], [Week]) as [NoWeekSales]
    from
    (
    select *
        , iif(Lag([Week], 1,null) OVER (PARTITION BY  [Shop_ID], [Product_ID], [Year]  ORDER BY  [Shop_ID], [Product_ID], [Year], [Week])=[Week]-1 ,1,0) as [WeekSale]
    from #sales
    ) a
    order by [Shop_ID], [Product_ID], [Year], [Week]
```

Comment: Thanks !! Works well !  
PS: Indeed my text had a typo : 2015-02-02 is week 6 and not 2015-01-02; similarly 2015-01-03 is not week 7 but anyway the code works well !